# Clause returning equivalent for MySql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, frameworks

I'm a student and we're learning how to build a framework.
My teacher gave me this line `insert into $table default values returning id$table`. 
I can't run it on mysql due to the clause returning. Can we replace it by another clause or line ?

CODE :

```
public function __construct($id=null) {
        $class = get_class($this);
        $table = strtolower($class);
        if ($id == null) {
            $st = db()->prepare("insert into $table default values returning id$table");
            $st->execute();
            var_dump(db()->errorInfo());
            $row = $st->fetch();
            $field = "id".$table;
            $this->$field = $row[$field];
```

Thanks